# Expresso Store rounding tax rates

Tags: expresso-store

Is there a setting in Store somewhere that is rounding tax rates on me? I have a product in the cart for 150 with a tax rate of 23%. This should equal 34.50 in tax, and the total should be 184.50, but it is 185.

I saw in store 1.6.4 there was an option in general tab to 'round after tax' but this seems to be missing in 2.0.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would upgrade to Store 2.1, there are a few improvements and fixes to tax calculation in the latest version (especially when discounts apply to your products).

My guess is that possibly there is some shipping or handling also affecting your cart total, which might be affecting the tax total. Either way, using your example I would expect 150 + 23% = 184.50, which is neither of the numbers you mentioned above.

Comment: Sorry yeah math, that should be the total. There's no shipping or handling applied ot the cart, but I will try and upgrade the software anyhow to be sure.

Comment: did the payment gateways change in this version? How would I include a custom subscription method?

Comment: Upgraded and the rounding still gives me .00 as opposed to .50 in the decimal places. Also lost my payment gateway in the mix, so not sure if it is even working now. I looked in the DB and the payment method is still there, although it doesn't appear in my payment method list. Any ideas on either of these?

Comment: Ok one more development. When I change the decimal places to 2 in my product tag, I get 150.00, which I want to display at 150 (no decimals). When I add to cart, I get the 2 decimal places now, but is there any way to only show the 2 places in the cart only?  - All of this notwithstanding, I am not sure where my payment method has gone.

Comment: @Aaron Will this up via email.

Answer (score 1):

Just for anyone's reference should you come across this, what I did to solve the issue was:

1. Create a text field with $150 (text with no .00) in it and displayed this on my product page.
2. Put the decimal setting to 2 in store, which allowed the VAT/Tax to show to two decimal places, as well as prices.

All works the way it should. Payment gateways are another matter altogether.

Comment: Oh, you didn't mention you had decimal places set to 0 in the settings. That would do it :). BTW If all of your products are whole numbers an easier way to display the price the way you want would be `${price_val}`.